# What kind of widget can cover all widgets as an overlay?

Tags: qt

I have a dialog window with many widgets inside.

[image]

The `QDialog` have a Vertical Layout and there I have placed all other widgets I wanted the dialog to have.

I am now wondering is it possible to add any kind of widget to play as some sort of overlay for the whole dialog and cover it on top ?

If that is possible what kind of widgets should I add and what kind of settings should I apply on it ?

As I it is now If I try to add new widget it aligns between the existing elements whenver I place it in the vertical layout. Looks like I can't figure out a way to add new element that does not obey the vertical layout of the QDialog and cover all the elements.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think the graphical Designer doesn't really support overlapping widgets in a layout. On code side, you can do it with QGridLayout. Or just manually (meaning in code, possibly overriding `resizeEvent()`) put the overlay widget directly as your login widget's child _without_ putting it in layout.